# Binary addition in C, from Arrays

Tags: c, gcc, binary, c99, twos-complement

I am trying to add two 5bit binary numbers together in C.
It is for a two's complement conversion, I just need to add one to my original number.
I see that there is a wealth of code available on the net but I can't get it to function in my implementation., I am getting **'00010' from this execution where it should be '00100'**

Here it is

```
int addBinary(int a[], int b[], int sum[]);

int main(){
   int i=0;
   int g =0;
   int sum[5];

   sum[0] =0;
   sum[1] =0;
   sum[2] =0;
   sum[3] =0;
   sum[4] =0;

   int b[5];
   b[0] =0;
   b[1] =0;
   b[2] =0;
   b[3] =0;
   b[4] =1;

   int set[5];
   set[0] =0;
   set[1] =0;
   set[2] =0;
   set[3] =1;
   set[4] =1;

   addBinary(set,b,sum);

 }


int addBinary(int a[], int b[], int sum[]){
    int i, c = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 5 ; i++){
       sum[i] = ((a[i] ^ b[i]) ^ c); // c is carry
       c = ((a[i] & b[i]) | (a[i] & c)) | (b[i] & c);
    }

    sum[i] = c;
    int z=0;
    for(z=0; z<5; z++) {
       printf("%d",sum[z]);
    }

    return c;
}
```

Comment: What´s with that indentation? Are you really writing it that way?

Comment: Why use a 32/64-bit int for every 0/1? Why a parameter b if you just want to add 1 every time?

Comment: And what´s the problem in the first place?

Comment: I was having problems with stack overflow recognising my code.

Comment: These arrays are just placeholders while I test the addition, real data source is from elsewhere. Original post updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running your addition from MSB to LSB, carrying in the wrong direction.

Either change your loop to start from `i=4` and count `i` down, or change the order of the bits in your array so that `a[0]` is the LSB and adjust your printout loop (which would make more sense IMO).